# open picture links in new page with php

Tags: php, css, image, feed

I have the code to dump pics in a directory and produce the result in a feed like instagram, i just want it to open the image onto a page with css and area for the picture already plotted out. I just need a jumping off point to open the images individually.

Comment: open them individually when they're clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
<?php
    $dest = "index.php?id=" . SHOWPIC . "&path=" . $path;
?>
<a href="<?php echo $dest; ?>">
    <img alt="Photo" src="<?php echo $path;?>">
</a>
```

SHOWPIC here is a constant that contains an integer. index.php should have something like:

```
if($_REQUEST["id"] == SHOWPIC)
    require_once "showpic.php";
```

$path in my example is meant to contain the path to the image displayed.

showpic.php will then read the contents of `$_REQUEST["path"]` and display the pic. That's also the place where you can add CSS or whatever you like to the site.